# NamedTuple with default values

Tags: python, namedtuple

I'm trying to use a function with a parameter of namedTuple which has default values.
I tried this. Is that somehow possible?

```
from typing import Optional, NamedTuple
    
Stats = NamedTuple("Stats", [("min", Optional[int]), ("max", Optional[int])])
    
def print(value1: Stats=None, value2: Stats=None):
    print("min: ", value1.min)
    print("max: ", value1.max)
        
print()
```

Comment: why are you using this form of `typing.NamedTuple`? Why not use it with `class(NamedTuple): ...` which is the whole point?

Comment: Note, the way to add defaults is to assign to `Stats. _field_defaults`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you please give an example ?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga of a solution you are thinking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rename your `print()` function**, first you're using the built-in function name `print` which is bad style, secondly then you make a recursive call to `print()` inside `print()` (and I'm sure you meant to call the actual built-in `print()` inside function's body).

**Second, use [`collection.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)** class to implement actual type of tuple, like following:

Also type annotations are not needed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NCsIwEIX3OcXgJh0IYlpRKXgK3YmLoCkW8kebSj19HUKrrZhNMt9782YSXvHhXTEMVeMt3Lwx@hZr71qobfBNBKesvscuGM3YKarYnrsAxxnOeMJcwIXb2tHNrer5VcBdV6ozsSX7pRCwvyIDOow4hKZ2scqeynRakmGKzlBAgvkcUiCVcoNYpojUna1onCxhNXbINdW40FW/1FWP7Ccg/xryfwFLPQWMu@P0@KwpcwFySz/4kh2RAyIbhjc)

```py
from collections import namedtuple

StatsTup = namedtuple('Stats', ['min', 'max'], defaults = [3, 7])
    
def printf(value1 = StatsTup(), value2 = StatsTup(max = 10)):
    print("min1: ", value1.min)
    print("max1: ", value1.max)

    print("min2: ", value2.min)
    print("max2: ", value2.max)

printf()
printf(StatsTup(12, 14), StatsTup(16, 18))
```

Output:

```
min1:  3
max1:  7

min2:  3
max2:  10

min1:  12
max1:  14

min2:  16
max2:  18
```

As you can see in code and output above I'm passing named tuple as default parameters to funcion. You can omit tuple's fields values if you provide `defaults = [...]` like I did. If you provide such defaults then you may provide no values to tuple like `StatsTup()` or some values like `StatsTup(max = 123)` or all values like `StatsTup(min = 20, max = 35)`.

---

Solution above works only starting with `Python 3.7`, for older versions of Python do following:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LCsIwEEX3@YrBTTNQxLSiIvgVug9BUyzkRZtq/fo6BO1DzCaZc@femYRXvHtXDkPVeAtXb4y@xtq7FmobfBPBKatvsQtGM3aOKraXLsBphnmWcJZDZmsHVvUZjp1rKZ1@Skn3TVeqM7GVkuy8zGGPDOgwEiA0tYsVfyjTaUH6188xhwSLOaQZVIoN4jFFJDdf0XhxhNXHIdZU40JX/VJXPbKfgGJqKP4FLPUU8Nkdv49xTVHkILb0g4nsiBwQ2TC8AQ)

```py
from collections import namedtuple

StatsTup = namedtuple('Stats', 'min max')
StatsTup.__new__.__defaults__ = (3, 7)
    
def printf(value1 = StatsTup(), value2 = StatsTup(max = 10)):
    print("min1: ", value1.min)
    print("max1: ", value1.max)

    print("min2: ", value2.min)
    print("max2: ", value2.max)

printf()
printf(StatsTup(12, 14), StatsTup(16, 18))
```

Comment: What's the point of leaving `Stats = NamedTuple("Stats", [("min", Optional[int]), ("max", Optional[int])])`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The only point of leaving it was to keep type annotations, it is really not needed if annotations are not necessary. I kept them only because original OP's question contained it, so I improved that code. But anyway thanks for pointing this out, I just updated my answer to include also cleaner version without any type annotation.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense, it doesn't type annotate `StatsTup`, which is what you end up using anyway

Comment: unfortunetaly it doesn't work with Python 3.6.7, is any other solution ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You mean that `Stats` annotation doesn't correctly correspond to `StatsTup`? If not then do you know what is the correct way to annotation `StatsTup` arguments?

Comment: @Arty use it the way it was intended to be used, using `class Stat(NamedTuple): ...` and annotate the fields

Comment: @JohnMarek Yes it starts working from `3.7`, give me some minutes, I'll implement 3.6 solution too.

Comment: @JohnMarek Just updated my answer with solution before `Python 3.7`, at the end of my answer. Put a look!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga According to [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) as it has example `Employee = NamedTuple('Employee', [('name', str), ('id', int)])` it looks like that actually original OP's annotation is correct. This kind of syntax (without using `class`) is actually an older syntax that is backward compatible. And if you see comments above, OP wants actually code to work on older Pythons like version `3.6`. Hence I suppose that original OP's annotation is right. It is not neccessary but right. I added Note to my answer about that annot not needed.

Comment: @Arty **but it isn't annotating the class you create with `collections.namedtuple`**, and in any case, you can use `class Stats(NamedTuple): ...` with annotations in Python 3.6, and it will even work wth default values, e.g. `min: Optional[int] = None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Alright, removed all type annotations from my answer. As they are not really necessary to solve OP's question.